# What is "接続章" supposed to mean in novels?

Tags: meaning, words

I've seen this a few times now near the end of light novels, "接続章", I'm not quite sure what it's supposed to mean? Literally it seems to translate as "connecting chapter". Is it supposed to be referring to a chapter that bridges one volume of a novel to the following one in a series of novels?

Answer (score 2):

接続章 is not a common word at all. Probably you will not see the word 接続章 again outside the story you're reading. Some Japanese light novels series use unique chapter names, and 接続章 should be one of these. Some other unique chapter names I've seen are:

- インターミッション (literally "intermission")
- 行間 (literally "between the lines")
- 幕間 (literally "between the acts/performances", [Entr'acte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%27acte))

Regardless of the name, the purpose is basically the same. From what I understand, they are generally short, do not contain "dynamic" episodes, but are used to conclude several chapters (or one volume) before them. In this sense, it is similar in purpose to epilogues, except that they do not close the entire series. Sometimes they have catchy scenes/lines at the end, which attract readers to the next volume/chapter (effectively working as "a bridge"). Sometimes chapters that have unique names like these may contain side stories totally irrelevant to the main story.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it supposed to be referring to a chapter that bridges one volume of a novel to the following one in a series of novels?

Yes, it is.

予備知識：
小説の構成の単位は、大きい順に 編 > 章 > 節 だとして説明します。本は適当な厚さでないと取り扱いにくいので一つの小説でも複数の本に分割する（＝分冊する）ことがあります。その場合の単位は「巻」で、これはvolumeに対応する用語だろうと思います。分冊することと、「編」「章」「節」とは直接の関係はありません。

「接続章」という漢字の並びから、
何となく意味は分かりますが、質問者が「I've seen this a few times now near the end of light novels　小説の終わり近くに見かける」とありますので、「接続章」の理解で合っているのかなと思った位の私の認識です。私の理解からは、「接続章」という言葉あるいは用語は、日本語でまだ意味が定着していないと思います。

「接続章」の役割として、
「bridge」という解釈は非常にうまいと思います。私が小説家なら、この「接続章」には、この「編」のまとめと、次の「編」への「伏線を置く to lay an underplot」だろうと思います。

「最終章」という言葉があります。
「接続章」と似ていますが、日本語としては確立しており、小説でも使われます。「最終章」という表現を採用する作家は小説の最後の章としてこの章を配置します。この「最終章」から類推しますと、「接続章」は、質問者の想定するとおり、ある「編」の最後に配置される「章」と解釈して良いように思います。

インターネットで「接続章」を調べましたが、きちんとした説明や辞書の掲載はありませんでした。かろうじて、小説での[実例](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n2119bm/)が見つかりました。

しかし、この実例を見ますと、第２編に当たる部分の最初に「接続章」とあります。作者は「Ｒ・グレイ」となっていますが、この小説は外国語からの翻訳小説ではなく、日本人である「Ｒ・グレイ」が書いたものだと思われます。

従ってＲ・グレイさんは質問者の解釈と違って、
「Brumaire」という題名の小説の「運命の別れ道
」という「編」の最初の「章」に「接続章」という用語を使っています。
内容を十分読んでおりませんが、一般にこの位置に「接続章」を置くなら、前編を思い出していただくための簡単な説明と本編を期待さすための導入的な内容になるのでしょう。

「接続章」に対する私の全体の感想として、
質問者の解釈は合っていると思います。また、その配置すべき位置は、Ｒ・グレイさんのBrumaireと違いますが、ある「編」の末尾の方がふさわしいように思います。